# Web Scraping with Queries produces 'Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, runtime-error

I recorded a macro. It works on the machine I recorded it on (Windows 10, Office 365 Pro)

I need the workbook to be transferable. When I send the workbook to others they get:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I've tried it on 2010 and on another copy of 365. Both return the error.

The macro is supposed to get affiliate information for MLB teams from the website:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_League

Here is my code:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Current teams[edit]", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_League""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Source{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""Division"", type text}, {""Team"", type text}, {""MLB Affiliation"", type text}, {""City"", type text}, {""Stadium"", type text}, {""Capacity"", type number}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordere" & _
    "d Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""MLB Affiliation"", ""Team"", ""Division"", ""City"", ""Stadium"", ""Capacity""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Reordered Columns"",{""Division"", ""City"", ""Stadium"", ""Capacity""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Current teams[edit]"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$O$9")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Current teams[edit]]]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Current_teams_edit"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Range("Current_teams_edit").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A35").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("M2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11],R34C[-12]:R49C[-10], 2, FALSE)"
Range("M3").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
Range("M2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M31"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("M2:M31").Select
Columns("O:O").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
Range("M2:M31").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("A34:C49").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Current teams[edit]").Delete
```

This is line is highlighted:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Current teams[edit]", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_League""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Source{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""Division"", type text}, {""Team"", type text}, {""MLB Affiliation"", type text}, {""City"", type text}, {""Stadium"", type text}, {""Capacity"", type number}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordere" & _
    "d Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""MLB Affiliation"", ""Team"", ""Division"", ""City"", ""Stadium"", ""Capacity""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Reordered Columns"",{""Division"", ""City"", ""Stadium"", ""Capacity""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
```

Comment: The [`Queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.queries) object was introduced in Office 2016. What version do they have?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've tried it on 2010 and on another copy of 365. Both return the same run-time error.